# What I have to do that menu will be on the top side of slider?

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, slider

I have a problem concerning my mobile menu and slider. I want the menu will on the top side of the slider. But when I'm clicking on the menu icon, the menu isn't shown. I tried in many ways but I still not solved the problem. Thank you in advance.
`



lorem

```
<body>
   <header>
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
        </label>
<img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
        <ul>
            <li class="el1"><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
            <li class="el1"><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
            <li class="el1"><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
            <li class="el1"><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide slide1">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Slide1</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio corrupti nemo incidunt deserunt obcaecati vero dolor explicabo tempore, rem quas cum vitae magni dolores. Delectus voluptatem dicta quam assumenda est.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide2">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Slide2</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio corrupti nemo incidunt deserunt obcaecati vero dolor explicabo tempore, rem quas cum vitae magni dolores. Delectus voluptatem dicta quam assumenda est.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide3">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Slide3</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio corrupti nemo incidunt deserunt obcaecati vero dolor explicabo tempore, rem quas cum vitae magni dolores. Delectus voluptatem dicta quam assumenda est.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide1">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Slide1</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio corrupti nemo incidunt deserunt obcaecati vero dolor explicabo tempore, rem quas cum vitae magni dolores. Delectus voluptatem dicta quam assumenda est.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code: https://codepen.io/FilipoV/pen/ExNowKM

Answer (score 0):

you will be use z-index:1; in your css.

```
nav ul {
 float: right;margin-right: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```